# Cannot redirect after login in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, blazor

I've the following blazor login component:

```
@page "/access/login"
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Identity.Shared;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

@inject IHttpClientFactory httpClientfactory
@inject IConfiguration configuration;
@inject ILogger<Login> logger
@inject IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<form id="logincontainer">
  <div id="header">
    <h2>My Service - Login</h2>
    <img id="logo" src="images/256/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <div id="wrong-password">
    @wrongPassword
  </div>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" @bind="_loginModel.Email" required><br>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" @bind="_loginModel.Password" required><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" @bind="_loginModel.RememberMe" name="rememberme">
  <label for="rememberme">Remember me</label><br>

  <input type="submit" @onclick="OnLoginClick" value="Login">
  <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot password?</a> or <a href="/registration">Register</a>
</form>

@code {
  private LoginViewModel _loginModel { get; set; } = new LoginViewModel();
  private string wrongPassword { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  private async void OnLoginClick()
  {
    try
    {
      logger.LogInformation("Login selected for user " + _loginModel.Email);
      var client = httpClientfactory.CreateClient();
      var uri = createLoginUri();

      if (hostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
      {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
      }
      var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, _loginModel);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        wrongPassword = string.Empty;
        var responseModel = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResponseModel>();
        NavigateToDashboard(responseModel.Result);

      }
      else
      {
        wrongPassword = "Wrong login data, please re-enter them.";
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      if (e.InnerException != null)
      {
        logger.LogError("Exception when sending login request: " + e.Message + ". Inner exception: " + e.InnerException.Message);
      }
      else
      {
        logger.LogError("Exception when sending login request: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }

  void NavigateToDashboard(LoginResponseModel data)
  {
    if (data.Roles.Contains(Role.OfficeAdministrator))
    {
      logger.LogInformation("User is an office administrator. Redirecting to his dashboard.");
      navigationManager.NavigateTo("/officeadministrator/dashboard", true);
    }
    else
    {
      logger.LogError("Cannot redirect from login page");
    }
  }

  Uri createLoginUri()
  {
    var hostname = configuration["Services:FrontendGateway:Host"];
    var url = hostname + "/" + configuration["Services:FrontendGateway:EndPoint:Login"];
    return new Uri(url);
  }

}
```

When I perform the login, I send the request, and the response is ok. Then I go to the `navigationManager.NavigateTo("/officeadministrator/dashboard", true);` line for redirecting to the main dashboard, but nothing happens I cannot see any error in the log.

The page link should be correct, because this is the (empty for now) page that I want to show after the login:

```
@page "/officeadministrator/dashboard"

<h3>Office Administrator Dashboard</h3>

@code {

}
```

So what I'm doing wrong? What should I do in order to perform the redirection after the login?

Comment: Do you have the **@attribute [Authorize]** at Imports file? If this is the case. Then You have to set the user to the authentication state.